# How to retrieve data from json response with scrapy?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python.

This is my url:

https://www.workingnomads.co/jobsapi/job/_search?sort=expired:asc,premium:desc,pub_date:desc&_source=company,category_name,description,location_base,instructions,id,external_id,slug,title,pub_date,tags,source,apply_url,premium,expired,use_at

My code:

```
def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        print("============================================================================================================================")
        print(jsonresponse["hits"]["hits"])
```

It returns the response in JSON format which looks like this.

[image]

How can I get the value of a specific key?

this one is the postman response

[image]

i want to retrive `apply_url` key value.

Comment: Which key(s) exactly do you want to retrieve? Where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: see my edited quetion please@petezurich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to access:

```
['hits']['hits'][x]['_source']['apply_url']
```

Where x is the number of items/nodes under `hits`. See https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.22e871cf105e40a5ba32408f6aa5afeb&right=cloud.e1f56c3bd6824a3692bf3c80285ae727

As you can see, there are 10 items or nodes under hits -> hits. `apply_url` is under `_source` for each item.

```
def parse(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    print("============================================================================================================================")
    for x, node in enumerate(jsonresponse):
        print(jsonresponse['hits']['hits'][x]['_source']['apply_url'])
```

For example, `print(jsonresponse['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['apply_url'])` would produce:

`https://boards.greenhouse.io/mesosphere/jobs/1422922?gh_jid=1422922`